# AngularJS Custom Directive - Setting attribute equal to scope object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a feed of posts, where the post object specifies a type value, which then specifies a template for the post. I got a custom directive built but I'm having issues.

JS

```
  myApp.controller('FeedCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.posts = [
      {'title': 'Post 1',
       'type': 'post',
       'snippet': 'Vim id noster platonem definitionem...',
      }
    ];
  });    

  myApp.directive('myPost', function () {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        title: '=',
        type: '=',
        snippet: '=',
      },

      templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
        return './templates/'+attr.type+'.html'
      }
    };
  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="FeedCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <my-post title='post.title' type='post.type' snippet='post.snippet'></my-post>
 </div>
</div>
```

doesn't work... but when I change the type attr to

```
<my-post type="post"></my-post>
```

it works and passes all of the scope data into the post.html template. What's the difference? Why doesn't it pass 'post.type' over to the directive, but it passes everything else just find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<my-post title='post.title' type='{{post.type}}' snippet='post.snippet'></my-post>
```

And change this:

```
scope: {
    title: '=',
    type: '@',
    snippet: '=',
}
```

Comment: this did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The template is requested before the scope is initialized. You could remove the `type` from the isolate scope and change the HTML to:

```
<my-post title='post.title' type='{{post.type}}' snippet='post.snippet'></my-post>
```

as @karaxuna suggested.

Comment: bah can't upvote you guys but thank you! got it solved.